# How to unblock access for IP address in Drupal REST services?

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8

My web application, using Drupal 8 as backend, recently stopped logging to Drupal (I was heavily testing login form).

Response from login request to Drupal says: "Too many failed login attempts from your IP address. This IP address is temporarily blocked."

I can log to Drupal directly from the same IP adress and there is no blocked IP visible in "IP address bans" (/admin/config/people/ban).

I have tried to edit /core/modules/user/config/install/user.flood.yml, but without success.

I would like:

1. Unblock my IP address.
2. Set less strict criteria for blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit Drupal database: Find table "flood" and delete all rows.

However, I would prefered a module for it. "Ban" module does not solve the problem (shows no banned IPs).